# What is the meaning and usage of shine in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, sentence

the sentence is ''the devils shone mirrors too.''and I don't know how to understand the meaning of shone here

Comment: "The **devil** shone mirrors too, shone them to distract Muslims during prayer.” - in your course material about _The Kite Runner_.

Comment: You should include the source of your quote.  The meaning of shine seems entirely literal and well within the senses in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the meaning of "to shine" is to make something brighter or polish something. I think in this context it is metaphorical and it means  "to highlight one's faults". Since we are talking about the devil it makes sense. He is polishing mirrors (a tool that lets you see your own reflection) so that you can more clearly see your own faults.

Comment: Nope, the devil (singular) polished mirrors to distract Muslims in prayer.

Comment: I don't know, it was just my 2 cents to help him understand.

Answer (score 0):

To shine (verb) something can be to polish it (e.g. with a cloth) so that it is free from dirt and reflects a lot of light (becomes shiny). Past tense: shone.

Comment: Thanks, I fully understand and I noticed that you have posted the right reference of this sentence. With your reference and explanation, I think I understand, literarily means the devil polishes the mirror to distract people.